# Easy, but doubts - Annualize daily turnover

Tags: options, black-scholes, portfolio-management, risk

I am fairly certain I am correct but I just want to double-check on portfolio turnover calculation. I need to annualize the daily turnover rate. To calculate, the daily turnover, I am using the following formula:

[image]

where N is the total number of securities and wj,t+1 is the weight of security j after rebalance and wj,t is the weight of security j before rebalance.

Full formula can be found here: https://breakingdownfinance.com/trading-strategies/passive-investing/portfolio-turnover/

I need to convert this number to an annualized number so I take the output and multiply it by SQRT(260). Is that correct? I am doubting myself because I am unsure if it needs to be multiplied by SQRT(260) or just 260.

Comment: You do this trading 260 times in a year (slightly less because of a handful of market holidays) , so you multiply by 260. I am not sure where you got the idea for the square root.

Comment: @noob2 I guess i confused myself with volatility, thanks for your help!